# Uploading File with Dio on Flutter without FormData

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to upload a file to the Dropbox API from a Flutter app. I am using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio).

Here is my request:

```dart
try {
  FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      filePath,
      filename: 'MyFile.db',
    ),
  });

  final dio = Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $dropboxAccessToken';
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
  dio.options.headers['Dropbox-API-Arg'] =
      '{ "mode": "overwrite", "mute": false, "path": "/MyFile.db" }';

  final response = await dio
      .post('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload', data: data);
  print('Success!');
  print(response);
} on DioError catch (error) {
  print(error.response);
}
```

It seems that Dio adds an additional `boundary` header when using `FormData` because this is the response I get:

```
Error in call to API function "files/upload": 
Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header: "multipart/form-data; boundary=--dio-boundary-0043340702"
```

The `Content-Type` header has to be `application/octet-stream`.

How can I upload a file in Dio without `FormData`? Or alternatively, how I can use `FormData` with a `application/octet-stream` content type and not inherit the custom header that Dio's `FormData` adds?